# Using vim, how can I find two words that are in a row and replace it with three words in a row in a txt file?

Tags: vim

For instance, I need to find double words like "Saw saw" and replace it with triple words like "Saw saw saw" in a txt file.

I'm thinking I'll be using `:%s/pattern/replace/g`

There is going to be multiple instances of this in the txt file, so I need to write something that would be universal, or work for different words.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is:

```
%s/\c\([Ss]aw\) \1/\1 \1 \1/g
```

where `\1` is a backreferece for the first capturing group `\([Ss]aw\)`. To force lowercase for second and third occurrences include `\l` in the replacement string:

```
%s/\c\([Ss]aw\) \1/\1 \l\1 \l\1/g
```

Comment: You can do it without capturing groups if you use & in the replacements.

Comment: Note that `\1` is not only used in the replacement string, but also in the pattern `\(saw\) \1`.

Comment: Eh, typing `saw saw` really isnt so bad, but i do see that now